# Unable to run query

Tags: php, sql

when i run my php page this error show:

> Unable to run query:Unknown column 'NUM_OPTIONAL_COLLEGE_COURSE' in 'field list'

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO MAJOR (`COL_NO`, `DEPT_NO`, `YEAR`, `NUM_OPTIONAL_UNI_COURSE`,
     `NUM_MANDATORY_UNI_COURSE`, `NUM_OPTIONAL_COLLEGE_COURSE`,
     `NUM_MANDATORY_COLLEGE_COURSE`, `NUM_OPTIONAL_DEPT_COURSE`, `NUM_MANDATORY_DEPT_COURSE`,
     `NUM_FREE_COURSE`, `NUM_CUSHIONS_COURSE`, `NUM_OF_CREDIT`)
     VALUES('$myq1','$myq2','$myq3','$myq4','$myq5','$myq6','$myq7','$myq8','$myq9',
     '$myq10','$myq11','$myq12')";
```

can you help me in this ?

Comment: You're SQL injecting yourself. Use PDO/MySQLi with prepared statements and bound variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no column named `NUM_OPTIONAL_COLLEGE_COURSE` in table `MAJOR`. Re-check your column name, most probably its a spelling mistake.

Comment: i check it a same column name

Answer (score 0):

The Error says it all

Verify `NUM_OPTIONAL_COLLEGE_COURSE` is the column name in the schema

Answer (score 0):

Most errors occur if you have a column like " NUM_OPTIONAL_COLLEGE_COURSE" (mind the space in front) - use your Database Management System and Copy the name of the column.

Comment: Please add the information, what the error was. This is useful for other users here too...
And if some answer here was the solution please mark it like that.

Comment: your answer is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Its a database schema error, The error means the column does not exist in table. You have to check out it carefully....You should also check, may be you are connected with wrong database. Once I also faced this type error, and my idiocy , I was runing my query on wrong database.